# How can I fix my implementation of modulo exponentiation?

Tags: python, math, floating-point, modulo, logarithm

So I've been trying to implement efficient modulo exponentiation. This is what I tried:

```py
def mypow(x, y, z):
    return x**(y % log(z, x))
```

However, the results are kind of strange,
My test Case:

```
z = 100
x = 2
for y in range(100):
    print(mypow(x, y, z), pow(x, y, mod=z))
```

Result:

```
1.0 1
2.0 2
4.0 4
8.0 8
16.0 16
32.0 32
64.0 64
1.2799999999999996 28
2.559999999999999 56
5.119999999999998 12
10.239999999999997 24
20.479999999999993 48
40.95999999999999 96
81.91999999999997 92
1.6383999999999987 84
```

This program is clearly flawed, but the correct solution seems to be there just after a few digits. For example, while 1.2799999999999996 != 28, 27.9999... ~= 28.

I have tried a few different x, y, and z, it seems to be a rather consistent pattern. While disappointed that the program is flawed. This pattern is quite interesting and I was wondering what is likely the cause here.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that modular exponentiation works like that? `return x**(y % log(z, x))` makes no mathematical sense.

Comment: Well, perhaps. But is there any explanation as to why we are seeing the pattern in the test case?

Comment: Since it is a  rather consistent pattern, I refuse to believe that it is a mere coincidence.

Comment: "why we are seeing the pattern ...?"  Exactly what pattern do you mean?  This seems to be the straightforward result of invalid algebra and natural floating-point representation?

Comment: The pattern you're seeing *does* have an explanation, but explaining it is a math question, not a programming question. If you want the pattern explained, you should rephrase this as a math question and ask it on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you want to fix your modular exponentiation code, then you should throw out your current implementation and look up how to do modular exponentiation - the pattern you're seeing cannot be turned into a usable modular exponentiation algorithm. Your code is unsalvageable and must be rewritten from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Actually, I have looked up how to do modular exponentiation, and know-how the build-in function does it. I would throw the code away if the results are utter nonsense. But due to the pattern, we are seeing here, I refuse to just let it go.

Comment: Perhaps you are right that this is a math problem rather than a programming question. Apologies.

Comment: The pattern, for those not seeing it, is that 1.28 ends with 28 (the correct answer), 2.56 ends with 56 (the correct answer), etc.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks, I had read the question too quickly - now I am among those seeing it!

Comment: `1.6383999999999987 84` breaks the pattern.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg It ends with ....8399999..., which is actually ....84

Comment: Please read carefully 1. **6** 383999999999987  **8**4

Comment: @TIM Please note that the way to mark a question as solved is different on SO: you can mark an answer as accepted (checkmark at the left of the answer), but you're not supposed to edit the title or the question.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg `1. 6383999999999987` is just the approximation,  due to rounding errors/float representation, of the exact value which is `2**14 / 100**2 = 1. 6384`, which ends with 84. See my answer below for the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula in the question,

```
x ** (y % log(z, x))
```

can be rewritten

```
x ** (y - k*log(z, x))
```

where k is the integer result of the division of `y` by `log(z, x))`.

This can be further rewritten as

```
(x**y) / (x**(k*log(z, x)) = (x**y) / (x**ln(z, x))**k
```

which is simply

```
x**y / z**k
```

The pattern only appears because `z = 100`: `x**y % 100` is the number formed by the last two digits of `x**y`, and these last two digits also appear at the end of the division of `x**y` by `100**k`, which is a power of 10.

(For example, `123456 % 100 = 56`, and `123456 / 100**2 = 12.3456`)

So, there would be no pattern at all to observe if `z` weren't a power of 10.

Comment: Thanks you for this explanation! Now I feel kind of silly.

Comment: Well, don't. If you've learnt something here, that's a gain...

Comment: As a side note, note that if you feel that an answer answered your question, you may accept it (checkmark on the left).

Comment: We can also characterize `k` as the integer needed to put `y - k*log(z, x)` in the half-open interval `[0, log(z, x))`, or equivalently, as the integer needed to put `x ** (y - k*log(z, x))` in the half-open interval `[1, z)`, which is why all the results were between 1 and 100.